# TypeError: list insides must be integers or slices, not str

Tags: python

```
final_message = f"<u>Данные по всему миру:</u>\n<b>Заболевших: </b> 
{location['confirmed']:,}\n<b>Сметрей: </b>{location['deaths']:,}"
```

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: list insides must be integers or slices,  not str
```

Comment: Вы прочитали ошибку, что из нее поняли?

Answer (score 3):

Описано в ошибке("TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str"), индекс списка не может быть строкой. ваш объект location это список и обращаться к его элементам можно по индексу как location[0], где индекс это целое число и равно порядковому номеру в списке, если вы хотите хранить данные используя ключ-значение то поменяйте структуру объекта location на словарь:

```
location = {'confirmed': '123', 'deaths': '321'}

final_message = f"Данные по всему миру:\nЗаболевших: 
{location['confirmed']:}\nСметрей: {location['deaths']:}"
```

Comment: Зачем убирать запятые после двоеточий? `f'{5000000:,}'` ≡ `'5,000,000'`

Comment: потому что это работает со списком, со словарем придется делать исключение

Comment: Ошибка в вашем коде: **EOL while scanning string literal.**

Comment: @АндрейТаков Запятая добавляет разделители разрядов при форматировании числа. Это никак не связано ни со списками, ни со словарями.

Comment: @extrn Спасибо! +в копилку знаний